# issue with ray tracer light diffuse

Tags: c, opengl, raytracing

I wrote the light diffusing code and it's just not working I dont know why

this is the code I wrote for diffusing

```
            t_vec pi = vec_add(ray.org,vec_times_double(ray.dir, t));
            t_vec hp = vec_diff(light.pos, pi);
            t_vec normal = get_sphers_normal(sp, pi);
            double dot = vec_dot(normalize_vect(normal),normalize_vect(hp));
            printf("hitpoint : %lf\n", dot);
            put_pixel(mlx.img, x, y, rgb_to_int(sp.color)*double_abs(dot), resolution.width);
```

[image: this is the result I got]

Comment: Hi, even though I believe I spotted your problem (see my answer below) I strongly recommend to, at least, include the declarations of the relevant functions. Even better, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
 put_pixel(mlx.img, x, y, rgb_to_int(sp.color)*double_abs(dot), resolution.width);
                          ^-----------------------------------
```

You seem to be multiplying an integer by a double. I presume that `put_pixel` expects a 32-bit integer encoding the RGB color, in which case your double gets converted back to int, but in an un-meaningful way, giving those color bands. For example, if `sp.color = { 255., 0., 0. }` is a red surface, `rgb_to_int` converts it to `0xff0000`, multiplying it by `0.00390625` (dimly lit surface) and converting back to `int` gives `0x00ff00`, which is a bright green rather than a dark red.

You should rather use your *vector times scalar* function on the argument to `rgb_to_int`:

```
rgb_to_int(vec_times_double(sp.color, double_abs(dot)))
```

I assume here that `sp.color` is of type `t_vec`. If it's not then adjust your code accordingly.